# Facing issue in Latest Support Library v26.0.0-beta1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am facing weird issue in Latest support library.
I just migrated my project to the latest Support version provided by GOOGLE and as per google guideline

So the problem is can't find the ***cardView*** in latest support file. Is anyone facing this problem ?

here is my App Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0-rc2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.temp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'RestrictedApi'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_libs"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$support_libs"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
}

// REQUIRED: Google's new Maven repo is required for the latest
// support library that is compatible with Android O
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
    }
}
```

and here is the project gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.support_libs = '26.0.0-beta1'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please read question you down voter... Have you tried to migrate your project..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see **cardview** added to dependencies anywhere in your app gradle file. Try adding:

`compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'`

Comment: But i am using ext.support_libs = '26.0.0-beta1' version for Support library and as per google document Appcompat already contains the cardview so no need to add extra library for cardview. Lower Versions are working fine. But i am facing this issue in Android O migration

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies in gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
```

Comment: But i am using ext.support_libs = '26.0.0-beta1' version for Support library and as per google document Appcompat already contains the cardview so no need to add extra library for cardview. Lower Versions are working fine. But i am facing this issue in Android O migration

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat v7 don't contain CardView, you need to make the explicit claim of that lib in your dependencies.

So, add `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_libs'` to your dependencies.